# Regex to ignore commented lines C++

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to use regex to find all variable initializations or assignments in code.
Currently I have

```
(\w+|\w[_])\s*=\s*(\d+\.\d+|.*)
```

which works but also finds commented out code like 
`// a = 100;` which I don't want it to do. I've tried

```
([^/]\w+|\w[_])\s*=\s*(\d+\.\d+|.*)`
```

which I thought should ignore strings that start with / but that doesn't work.

Edit:

For example I'd like it to find lines like
`b = 200;`
but not `// c = 3;`

Comment: For starters, `//` is the comment leader in C++ (or `/*` for C-style comments), not `\\\`

Comment: It gets worse if you don't want to match code in string constants and embedded in comment blocks aka: `/* a = 100 */ Not sure regex will get you absolutely everything.

Comment: @PaulRoub That was embarrassing, fixed now.

Comment: If you have the option i would rather recommend you use `libclang` to properly parse your source files and extract the information from the AST. Regex is just too weak to get all the edge cases right.

Comment: @RedX is right: trying to get regexes alone to parse (or even lex) C++ properly is pretty much an exercise in futility.

Comment: I'll have a look at libclang instead, cheers.

Comment: Give some sample inputs and tell whats your expected output.

Comment: @depsai I've added an example

Comment: As @JerryCoffin says, it's probably too much to expect a single regular expression to do this.  You _can_ use multiple regular expressions for most of the lexing (C style comments are still an issue), but finding all of the initializations will probably require some parsing as well.

Comment: What about: `a = "//b=5"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try this take if necessary.

```
^(?:(?!\/\/).)*[a-z][a-z0-9\_]*\s*=\s*[0-9]+;
```

**SEE DEMO:** http://regex101.com/r/jE4vM0/3

Answer (score -1):

Use this regex and check if the first sub-match is `"//"`, if yes, it is after a comment.

```
(//)*\s*(\w+|\w[_])\s*=\s*(\d+\.\d+|.*)
```

For example `"var=5;"` will get three sub-matches: blank, `var`, and `5` while `"//var=5;"` will get **`//`**, `var`, and `5`.

Comment: Your regex produces an error: "Unescaped forward slash".  After fixing, it doesn't prevent the match of a commented line containing the text that was searched.  The OP wanted to exclude those lines in the matching criteria.